# How to update a recurrence occurence on ICal

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

I'm currently working with the ical format and need to handle recurring events.

I'm working directly with Icloud and have managed to create and delete recurring events.

However, I encountered some problems when trying to update a single occurence of the said recurrence.

For example, let's say I have an event called 'test' scheduled every day for a week.
How should I proceed to rename the occurence of Tuesday to 'other title'? Or even change the dates for this particular occurrence ?

I tried to simply update the occurence by using it's ID but it seems to create a clone of it and not touch the real occurence. Moreover when trying to access the cloned event from the Icloud calendar interface it crashes.

So I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate some help :)

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear whether you are trying to update the occurence.

In any case, you should still have only one calendar resource but it should contain

- one "master" VEVENT, containing the base information,along with the RRULE,
- one VEVENT for each instance that is an "exception" to the base event, where each exception is identified by its RECURRENCE-ID.

RFC5545 does not have any example of such event but RFC5546 has something pretty close at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-4.4.8 (using RDATE instead of RRULE and no need for the METHOD property but you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Posting for future readers. For some reasons it's super hard to find a working example of `RECURRENCE-ID`

The following resource will repeat an event 'test' (10AM - 1PM UTC) everyday for 10 days starting on Jan 13th, 2021, EXCEPT on Jan 15th 2021, the event will be called 'test except me' and starts 3PM - 6PM UTC.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:232392939239293293@hello.me
DTSTART:20210113T100000Z
DTEND:20210113T130000Z
SUMMARY:test
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=10
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:232392939239293293@hello.me
DTSTART:20210115T150000Z
DTEND:20210115T180000Z
SUMMARY:test except me
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210115T100000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```